# Change meta description ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, meta-tags

I am trying to use angular plugin. But it does not work for **ionic**. Does anyone   knows how to set **ionic** meta description?

Comment: Please be more precise and clear... What do you mean with "angular plugin"?

Comment: Thank you for replying! Some plugin like ngMeta and anuglar-metatags